# Pass Input of Step Function to Glue JOb

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-step-functions

I'm trying to pass input from step function to Glue Job.
Following is my test state machine,
[image]

This is the code I'm using

[image]

This is the input I' giving to state machine,

**{
"Comment": "Insert your JSON here"
}**

Issue is that values are not passing to the Glue

Comment: check syntax https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-research-workshops/blob/2cf0d01f39dc83d0ab2fd539e568f8b857e00583/notebooks/building_data_lakes/cfn/sf_orch_glue.yaml#L116

Comment: Issue was solved. Issue was of the syntax. Thanks @PrabhakarReddy

Comment: I have added this as answer. Please mark it as answered if it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax that you are using is not valid. Please check below example or [this](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-research-workshops/blob/2cf0d01f39dc83d0ab2fd539e568f8b857e00583/notebooks/building_data_lakes/cfn/sf_orch_glue.yaml#L116) link for more.

```
GlueOrchestrationStateMachine:
        Type: "AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine"
        Properties:
            RoleArn: !GetAtt StepFunctionsServiceRole.Arn
            DefinitionString: !Sub |-
                  {
                    "StartAt": "Glue StartJobRun",
                    "States": {
                      "Glue StartJobRun": {
                        "Type": "Task",
                        "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync",
                        "Parameters": {
                          "JobName.$": "$.job_name",
                          "Arguments": {
                              "--REGION.$": "$.arguments.region",
                              "--TABLE_NAME.$": "$.arguments.table_name",
                              "--S3_OUTPUT_BUCKET.$": "$.arguments.s3_output_bucket",
                              "--S3_OUTPUT_KEY_PREFIX.$": "$.arguments.s3_output_key_prefix",
                              "--DATABASE_NAME.$": "$.arguments.database_name"
                          }
                        },
                        "InputPath": "$",
                        "ResultPath": "$.status",
                        "Next": "Start Crawler",
                        "Catch": [
                            {
                              "ErrorEquals": [ "States.ALL" ],
                              "Next": "Job Failure"
                            }
                        ]
                      },
                      
                  }
              }
```